# Which static code analysis tool can check 'Depth of conditional nesting' , 'Fan out' and 'Cyclomatic Complexity' rules?

Tags: static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd

I tried with PMD but it have only  'Cyclomatic Complexity'.

I find 'Fan out' rule in checkstyle.

Which tool has all these three rules?

Comment: From the official close reasons: questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved with Checkstyle tool.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Please also mark your answer as accepted so that the question doesn't show up as open anymore.